# jOOQ DSLContext: Correct autowiring with Spring

Tags: java, spring, jooq

I'm not sure if I'm getting [this](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.6/manual/sql-execution/performance-considerations/) right:

> "*... jOOQ's Configuration is not necessarily threadsafe, and queries are "attached" to their creating DSLContext.*"

I'm implementing the [Repository Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526874/Repositorypluspattern-cplusdoneplusright) so can I autowire the `DSLContext` like this for all my repositories?

```
public abstract class AbstractRepository {  

    private DSLContext ctx;

    public AbstractRepository(DSLContext ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public DSLContext getCtx() {
        return ctx;
    }
}

public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {
    public UserRepositoryImpl(DSLContext ctx) { super(ctx); }
}

public class LoginService eextends AbstractService {

    public UserRepository userRepository ;

    @Autowired
    public LoginService(DSLContext ctx) {    
        this.userRepository = new UserRepositoryImpl(ctx);
    }

    @Transactional
    public UserDTO login(String username, String password) {
        // Check if password is correct ..
        return userDto;
    }
}
```

Is there any reason why I would not assign the same instance of `DSLContext` to all my repositories

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionAwareDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider" name="connectionProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="transactionAwareDataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dsl" class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext">
    <constructor-arg ref="config" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration" name="config">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="connectionProvider" />
    <constructor-arg index="1"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="3"><null/></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="4"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="5"><value type="org.jooq.SQLDialect">POSTGRES_9_4</value></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="6"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="7"><null /></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- BEGIN Services -->

<bean id="loginService" class="com.mz.server.web.service.LoginService">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="dsl" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- END Services -->
```

but instead create for every repository a new instance?

Comment: It seems to me we don't have full picture. Could you please provide full wiring for all repositories?

Comment: @luboskrnac Hi! It's not really about the full picture here. My question here is basically if this is threadsafe. But I have added a service that I would want to autowire with the `DSLContext`.

Comment: Got your point and created answer.

Comment: Hmm, as you included also JOOQ transactional support into comment of my answer, I have to admit, I am not sure how JOOQ cooperates with `@Transactional`.  Therefore I deleted my answer to leave place for more qualified answers.

Comment: @luboskrnac alright! thank you for trying to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration is fine because there is no sensitive state inside of the configuration objects that you have configured.

In particular, the `ConnectionProvider` delegates connection handling to Spring, which solves things via `ThreadLocal` to guarantee that the `Connection` references returned from the transaction aware data source proxy aren't shared among threads / transactions.

This...

> jOOQ's Configuration is not necessarily threadsafe

... just means that implementors (e.g. of `ConnectionProvider`) are not required to provide thread safe implementations, which then means that `Configuration` cannot guarantee thread safety either.

Comment: Okay, got it :) I know I'm asking a lot lately but I have to learn fast as my time is getting limited as the next semester starts - so may I invite you to take a look at this question regarding [jOOQ and Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871216/jooq-spring-transaction-provider-transactional-not-working)?

Comment: @StefanFalk: No worries. As long as you ask publicly, others will profit as well. I'll look into that other question later.